# Test prices on shop findelements?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have little problem with my school project.

It's a shop test in Selenium / Java. This is the shopping query: https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=nothing+car&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Anothing+car

And I tried get all products prices in test.

Is there any other way than this?

```
String string = findelement(by.xpath("//[@id='result_0']/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a/span/span"))
System.out.println(string);
```

After printing that value, I need to check if the value < 20$, and return a failure if so.

Comment: Can you clarify what is your problem: *get all products prices in test* or *check if the value < 20$*? Could you also share what is `findelement()`? Common `findElement()` method will not return a *value* that can be compared with `20$`, but a `WebElement`...

Comment: Okay , i need to find one <20$ product and take them to the basket.. its my last problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use

```
//li[starts-with(@id,"result_")]//span[@class="sx-price-whole" and position()=last()]
```

to get *all* the highest prices (dollars only, no cents)

or

```
//li[starts-with(@id,"result_")]//span[@class="sx-price-whole" and position()=last() and .<20]
```

to get prices *that are lower than 20*

Answer (score 0):

here is the locator to get all `li` elements with minimal price < 20. Shipping not included.

```
//ul[@id='s-results-list-atf']//li[contains(@id,'result')][.//span[contains(@class,'sx-price-whole')][number(./text())<20]]
```

if you want to get `li` elements with MAX price < 20 - use this:

```
//ul[@id='s-results-list-atf']//li[contains(@id,'result')][.//span[contains(@class,'sx-price-whole')][last()][number(./text())<20]]
```

explanation:

> `//ul[@id='s-results-list-atf']//li[contains(@id,'result')]` - get all
>   `li` elements inside `ul` with goods
>
> `[.//span[contains(@class,'sx-price-whole')][...]]` - get all prices
>   of goods, and 1 more attribute to get those that has price lower 20
>
> `[number(./text())<20]` - sorting elements with price < 20